# Matlab symbolic function with normcdf

Tags: matlab

I have the following function for which I want to find the extrema using matlab.

[image]

That function has to use the "normcdf" function in matlab in order to get the results but when I'm trying to create the symbolic function I get back some errors.

The input I give is the following:

```
syms z fz t sz
fv = 1000 * ((z * fz * normcd(t,fz,sz)) / (20 * 50 * normcd(t,50,20))) + 1000 * normcdf((20 * 50 * normcd(t,50,20) + z * fz * normcd(t,fz,sz)) / 2000, 50 * normcd(t,50,20), 20) - 10 * z
```

and the errors I get back are the following:

```
??? Error using ==> sym.le at 11
Function 'le' is not implemented for MuPAD symbolic objects.

Error in ==> normcdf at 57
sigma(sigma <= 0) = NaN;
```

Does anyone know how I can get around that? Thanks in advance.

I forgot to mention that I use matlab version R2009a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around it. Instead of using `normcdf` one can use its equivalent equation with `erf` which then works fine.

```
normcdf(x,mu,sig) = (1+erf((x-mu)/sig/sqrt(2)))/2
```

Comment: Coming from a Mathematica background, this is just ridiculous :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to work for me:

```
>> syms z fz t sz
>> fv = 1000 * ((z * fz * normcdf(t,fz,sz)) / (20 * 50 * normcdf(t,50,20))) + 1000 * normcdf((20 * 50 * normcdf(t,50,20) + z * fz * normcdf(t,fz,sz)) / 2000, 50 * normcdf(t,50,20), 20) - 10 * z

>> subs(fv,{fz,sz,t,z},{1,2,3,4});

ans =

 809.2922
```

Take a look at the [Subs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/subs.html).

Comment: Which version of matlab are you using? I have R2009a. Maybe you have a newer version that I do.

Comment: I'm using `7.14.0.739 (R2012a)`.  Hopefully someone else chimes in.